# If TPM owner password set in linux, how to enter owner password in windows to enable bitlocker?

Tags: linux, disk-encryption, bitlocker, secure-boot, tpm

I have successfully taken ownership of, and used various features of, my tpm in linux, using tpm_takeownership and related applications.

Now when I try to enter the owner password in windows to enable bitlocker, it refuses to accept the owner password I am entering.

I wonder if windows has a different method from linux of either parsing the string, or hashing the password before presentation to the tpm for verification ?

Can someone shed some light on this issue ?

I would dearly love to be able to use the tpm to seal secrets in both windows and linux.